# Asp.Net Update Panel Required Field Validator Issue

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, validation

I have an update panel, and inside the update panel there is a dropdown and a required field validator which is associated with the dropdown and the autopostback of dropdown set to true.
now whenever user change the option the autopost back occure in updatepanel.. what i need is that if user pick the empty item from the dropdown it should not postback to the server and validator should fire.... but in my case the validators fire perfecty and also there is a postback and after the postback the required field validaor state is true.

what i need is to stop the postback if validator fails.

i have search for this problem alot but doe's not find any thing helpful.

Answer (score 1):

1- In DropDownList:

```
CausesValidation="True"
```

2- In Page_Load use string.Empty to value of first item:

```
 DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select...", string.Empty));
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
            CausesValidation="True" 
            onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="DropDownList1" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Empty"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Label>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code behind:

```
protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Label1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text;
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("Select...", string.Empty));
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("mehdi", "1"));
        DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem("ali", "2"));
    }
}
```